# Set value to zero if below certain value in rgb image array using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

trying to set value to zero where value is less than 255 in rgb image list using numpy. img[:,:,i][img < 255] = 0

```
img = np.asarray(cv2.imread("./labels/" + path))
img.shape # (480, 640, 3)

i = [0,1,2]
img[:,:,i][img < 255] = 0
np.unique(img[:,:,0], return_counts=True)
```

This doesn't change any value in the image.
Please let me know if anyone can help.

Comment: Why not just  `img[img < 255] = 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to first comment
img[img < 255] = 0

Answer (score 0):

This line of code sets the value to zero where value is less than 255 in an RGB image

```
img[img < 255] = 0
```